# ListView OnItemClickListener on PopupWindow not working (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview

I want to show a popupwindow that has a Listview, and when I click over a listview ítem, do something. To simplify my problem, I made the next example where it shows the problem: ítem click on listview is not working.

My popupwindow custom layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvData"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibInfo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"/>
```

My Map activity where I show the Popupwindow:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){
        mPopupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupwindow_custom_layout, null);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) mPopupView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        ListView lvData = (ListView) mPopupView.findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        ImageButton ibInfo = (ImageButton) mPopupView.findViewById(R.id.ibInfo);
        TextView txtListTitle = new TextView(this);
        ibInformacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("click on button");
            }
        });
        txtListTitle.setText("List Title");
        listaLineas.addHeaderView(txtListTitle);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        tvNombre.setText("Main Title");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.add("Test 1");
        adapter.add("Test 2");
        adapter.add("Test 3");
        adapter.add("Test 4");
        adapter.add("Test 5");
        adapter.add("Test 6");    

        lvData.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println("Click on list item");
            }
        });
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(mPopupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(this, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

Why the ibInfo's `setOnClickListener` Works fine, but the lvData's `setOnItemClickListener` (nor `setOnClickListener`) does nothing? What am I missing? (The list's scroll Works fine)

Note: I can't set `mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true)` because I will lose the clicks over the map (`onMapClick`, `onCameraChange`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to the listView

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Hope this will fix it!